# Heroku not reading requirement.txt file

Tags: python, heroku, requirements.txt

I am trying to deploy my python flask app to heroku but it keeps crashing and complaining about `bash: gunicorn: command not found`. I have my `requirement.txt` file in the root folder where my `Procfile` is also located. My python code is located in `src/server/`

Procfile contains: `web: gunicorn --pythonpath src/server/ route:app --preload`

I have gunicorn in my requirements file:

Is there something i'm missing?

```
     gunicorn==19.8.1
     Flask==0.12.2
     Flask-Cache==0.13.1
     Flask-Cors==3.0.2
     Flask-MongoAlchemy==0.5.1
     flask-mongoengine==0.9.5
     Flask-PyMongo==0.5.2
     Flask-WTF==0.14.2
     gevent==1.2.1
     greenlet==0.4.12
     pymongo==3.6.1
```

folder structure;

[image]

[image]

Comment: are you getting any error, can  you send the stack traces

Comment: I have updated the post with what i get when i run heroku log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating a new environment in Heroku. The previous environment seems not to be reading the requirement.txt file, I couldn't figure why.

Answer (score 2):

I faced a similar problem with my app. I just reset all my requirements by sending in an empty `requirements.txt` file. Then built my app. Then sent the original file. I don't understand why, but it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I am also having a similar problem like this on Heroku.  I created an IDENTICAL new project and magically it works.  Heroku has some bug related to ignoring requirements.txt