# Heroku - code="H10" error at the first line

Tags: python, flask, heroku

So I am trying to set up my website online and it printed "Build succeeded" but when I tried entering the website I get this error:
[image]

So I entered the command in the terminal and I had this error in my server:

```
File "/app/Server.py", line 1, in <module>
import requests
```

`requests` is included in `requirements.txt` I am not sure why I am getting this error
`Procfile`:

```
web: gunicorn --bind 127.0.0.1:5000 Server:app
```

I am working with python, flask, `Server.py` is the file name and `app = Flask(__name__)`

full log error:

```
2020-04-29T22:00:54.375570+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-04-29T22:01:02.512425+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-04-29T22:01:02.199124+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Starting gunicorn 20.0.4
2020-04-29T22:01:02.199914+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Listening at: http://127.0.0.1:5000 (4)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.200070+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Using worker: sync
2020-04-29T22:01:02.205899+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [9] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 9
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231965+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [9] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231967+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231990+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231991+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231991+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231992+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231992+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231992+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231993+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231993+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231993+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231994+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231994+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231994+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231995+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231995+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231996+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231996+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231997+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231997+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231997+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231998+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231998+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231998+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231999+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/Server.py", line 2, in <module>
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231999+00:00 app[web.1]: import requests
2020-04-29T22:01:02.231999+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
2020-04-29T22:01:02.234426+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [9] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 9)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.276833+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [10] [INFO] Booting worker with pid: 10
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288853+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [10] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288854+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288855+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288856+00:00 app[web.1]: worker.init_process()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288856+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 119, in init_process
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288856+00:00 app[web.1]: self.load_wsgi()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288857+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 144, in load_wsgi
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288857+00:00 app[web.1]: self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288858+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288858+00:00 app[web.1]: self.callable = self.load()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288859+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 49, in load
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288859+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.load_wsgiapp()
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288859+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 39, in load_wsgiapp
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288860+00:00 app[web.1]: return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288860+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 358, in import_app
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288861+00:00 app[web.1]: mod = importlib.import_module(module)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288861+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.8/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288861+00:00 app[web.1]: return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288862+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288862+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288863+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288863+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288863+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783, in exec_module
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288864+00:00 app[web.1]: File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288864+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/Server.py", line 2, in <module>
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288864+00:00 app[web.1]: import requests
2020-04-29T22:01:02.288865+00:00 app[web.1]: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
2020-04-29T22:01:02.289094+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [10] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 10)
2020-04-29T22:01:02.400999+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
2020-04-29T22:01:02.401112+00:00 app[web.1]: [2020-04-29 22:01:02 +0000] [4] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212826/discussion-on-question-by-patch-heroku-codeh10-error-at-the-first-line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the first problem was that I needed to install all of the modules to Pipfile(all the modules in the project). for some reason, my `requirements.txt` didn't go through if you insist to know why it doesn't work try to read [A question about it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50602030/heroku-not-reading-requirement-txt-file)(maybe re-modify it). the second problem was on my end: I put my program in `def main()` which you can not do as @mechanical_meat said "app needs to be available at the top level of the module"